What is the linguistic terminology for cases where the intonation or stress of a syllable determines its meaning?
What is the linguistic terminology for cases where the intonation or stress of a syllable determines its meaning? I'm not referring to tonal languages, but rather examples like the German word umfahren ([ˈʊmfaːɐn], 'to run over' vs. [ʊmˈfaːɐn], 'to drive around'). Both are written the same, but refer to completely opposite concepts. What is the exact terminology for such cases, and do similar phenomena exist in other languages?

Lexical stress? It’s not uncommon in languages to have lexical stress. A better example than German, which only has a few such cases, is Spanish which has many – for example, in regular first-conjugation verbs, stress is the only thing that distinguishes 1sg present from 3sg preterite (e.g., hablo /ˈaβlo/ ‘I speak_ vs habló /aβˈlo/ ‘(s)he spoke’). English sort of has it too, except that the unstressed vowels are reduced so they’re not quite the same (e.g., noun ˈrecord vs verb reˈcord).

Phonemic stress is another term often used in linguistics.

Aren't they just homographs?

@Nacht In languages using non-alphabetic scripts like Japanese, homographs can differ by much more than intonation or stress. E.g. 入る can be /iru/ or /hairu/ (partially related verbs with partially shared meanings); 行った can be /itta/ or /okonatta/ (past tense of unrelated verbs with unrelated meanings).

This is generally called contrastive stress (stress creates a contrast between words), lexical stress (stress is stored in the lexicon), or phonemic stress (stress is a phonemic quality). In English this tends to distinguish nouns from verbs, like próject (thing you work on) vs projéct (extend outward).

It should be noted contrastive stress is ambiguous as it could also refer to the stress in e.g. "I said comˈpetence, not conˈfidence".

“project” doesn’t quite give a minimal pair in English, since the vowel quality also changes — /ˈpɹɒd͡ʒ.ɛkt/ or /ˈpɹɐʊ.d͡ʒekt/ for the noun, /pɹəˈd͡ʒɛkt/ for the verb.  On the other hand incense (noun: stuff you burn for fragrance / verb: make angry) is I think a completely minimal pair in most dialects.
